# JavaScript declarations using strings

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, in JavaScript we can use strings to declare:
1) Object fields:

```
var obj = { "fi" : "val" };
```

2) Functions:
`var sum3 = new Function("arg1", "arg2", "return arg1 + arg2;");`

Is this all? Is it possible to declare something else using a string or a set of strings?

Comment: Are you need pass the object into function?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you...

Comment: *`something else`* declare means what?  *set of strings*?

Comment: Creating a variable in JavaScript is called "declaring" a variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, practically using a string or strings it is possible to declare: 
1) Object fields:
var obj = { "fi" : 42 };
obg['fi2'] = 43;
2) Functions:
var sum3 = new Function("arg1", "arg2", "return arg1 + arg2;");
3) Anything, if you pass the string to eval and "use strict" is not on:

```js
var code =  "var obj = { 'fie' : 42, 'sum' : function(a, b) { return a+b; } }";
eval(code);
alert(obj.fie);
alert(obj.sum(2, 2));
```